# Rows not refreshing when calling Custom SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I wanted to be able to display rows of my Listview in different colours according to their type. So I created a custom adapter using the code below.

```
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    Lectures_Adapter adapter = new Lectures_Adapter(this,R.layout.menu_item,cursor,FROM,TO);
    menuList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

the custom adapter uses this code -

```
public Lectures_Adapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from,int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    this.appContext=context;
    this.layout=layout;
    this.mycursor=c;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {     
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);   
    if (position > 0)
    {
        RelativeLayout rowFill = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowFill);
            String title = mycursor.getString(0);
            int myColor = 0;
            int myPos = title.indexOf("Nurse");
            int myPos2 = title.indexOf("masterclass");
            if (myPos >= 0)
            {
                myColor = Color.parseColor("#99FF66");
            }
            else if (myPos2  >= 0)
            {
                myColor = Color.parseColor("#FF99FF");
            }
            else
            {
                myColor = Color.parseColor("#FFFF66");
            }
            convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowFill).setBackgroundColor(myColor);                 
    }           
    return view;    
}
```

It all works fine and displays the rows in their appropriate colours but the first page is always unchanged (except for the first row) and when I select a row and return to the Listview the changes don't apply. How can I get the Listview to constantly keep to the Custom adapters settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first use this code in getView method:

```
if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.my_layout,null);
        } else {
            rowView = (View) convertView;
        }
```

use the following code where you want to apply your changes.

```
myListView.invalidateViews();
```

**Edit:**

put myListView.invalidateViews(); in your activity methods (UI). for example in

```
    myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    { 
            @Override public void onItemClick(
                    AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { 
                    myListView.invalidateViews(); 
            } 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply, I've put the code into the getView as requested like so -

```
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this.appContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflator.inflate(this.layout,null);
        } else {
            convertView = (View) convertView;
        }

    return view;
```

I'm not sure where to put the line myListView.invalidateViews(); but at the moment the situation remains the same as the Listview is not updating

Comment: put myListView.invalidateViews(); in your activity methods (UI). for example on `myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
     int position, long id) {
    myListView.invalidateViews();
   }
  });`

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `notifyDataSetChanged` on the listviews `adapter`. Make sure you do that on the UI thread.